# how to install gcc on mac using command line?

Tags: macos, installation

I need to install the gcc suite on an OS/X box using the command line.  As far as I can tell, the only way to do this is to install Xcode, which appears to only have a GUI install.  Surely, this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can install any package using command line with `installer` - the GUI is merely a convenience, you don't need to use it. For example

```
sudo install -pkg Xcode.mpkg -target /
```

You can also pick individual packages from the Xcode installation if you wish, for example `Packages/llvm-gcc4.2.pkg` contains just the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this:

http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/09/20/compiling-gcc-4-6-1-on-mac-osx-lion/

Mind you this is compiling the latest from source.

Answer (score 0):

You can download pre-built binaries from: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer